# Java Time Object with greater Hours (for Countdown)

Tags: java, android, parsing, type-conversion, java-time

I have this code: What this does is convert a String into a Time object.

```
  String time = "288:30:18";
  DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
  Date date = sdf.parse(time);
```

The main objective is that a user may input a Time in the format HH:MM:SS. The thing is that HH can be any number(>12, even>24). How do I keep the HH as it is ? 
In the above snippet, I am geting time as **12:30:18**. How do I prevent the HH part from getting parsed(***I want it to remain 288***)?

Comment: Don't try and make it a date. I'd use a Joda-Time `Interval`

Comment: could you give the code to me ? I want it to be parsed from string

Comment: Or you could use a Calendar - set (MINUTE, ...)  set (SECOND, ...)

Comment: Please give some code. I NEED it to be parsed from a string.

Comment: If you keep it as **288** then one would take **288** hours to know the exact time. If you want to keep it as it is then why are you using DateFormat? Just use that String only.

Comment: okay, more info. Its a countdown. I will get HH:MM:SS from separate EditTexts and make it a string, then pass it as a string intent to a service. So what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Parse the hours by yourself (using substring from index 0 to first ":".
2. Run above code (your code)
3. Set the hours in object "date" to the number you parsed.

Comment: This was always an option, but I wanted to know if methods already existed for parsing

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android much, but sometimes going for a simple solution like this is better off than struggling to find the "right" solution :)

Comment: its not about right. Its about making use of existing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out the best way for countdown in android. Here is the code:

```
  CountDownTimer c=new CountDownTimer(30000,1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }
}.start();
```